# Magento2 apply custom discount fully working with tax calculation

Tags: magento2, tax-calculation, custom-discount

I want to apply custom discount on cart items and my product price is tax included and I have used some references and in all the custom discount applied successfully but  after custom discount apply the tax calculation not working properly so I need custom discount working properly with tax calculation.